# How to store an operator in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, operation

I'm trying to store one of 3 random operators (+ or - or combine the preceding and succeeding entries in the list) in an array then call it back out later to perform an operation. Ultimately I want the program to be able to add, subtract, or combine a set list of integers by the random operator and return the total, but for now I would just like to solve the problem of storing and calling the "+" and the "-" in an array.

I've created a randomizer that outputs either a 0, 1, or 2. Depending on the output of the randomizer it sets an entry in my array to equal the string "+", "-", or "_" (for combine). I then set up a variable that stores the string as an integer (the set list of numbers in my array are strings which is why I did this in the first place), which of course doesn't work with "+", "-", or " _". I'm now thoroughly stuck and can't figure out what to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string oldlist[17];

int operationrandomizer;

int total;

std::string plus;
std::string minus;
std::string combine;

int oldlistint0;
int oldlistint1;
int oldlistint2;

int newlistint;

int main() {
   srand((unsigned)time(0));

    plus = "+";
    minus = "-";
    combine = "_";

    operationrandomizer = (rand()%3);

    if (operationrandomizer == 0) {
    oldlist[1] = combine;
     }

    else if (operationrandomizer == 1) {
        oldlist[1] = plus;
    }

    else if (operationrandomizer == 2) {
       oldlist[1] = minus;
    }

    oldlist[0] = "1";
    oldlist[1];
    oldlist[2] = "2";

    oldlistint0 = stoi(oldlist[0]);
   // oldlistint1 = stoi(oldlist[1]); // cant convert "+" to an int     bc + has no int value
    oldlistint2 = stoi(oldlist[2]);

    total = oldlistint0 + oldlistint1 + oldlistint2;
    std::cout << total << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm relatively certain that the randomizer and the array is functioning properly. I just need a way to store an operator in an array then pull it back out again.

Comment: "+", and "-" are text strings. There is no built-in transformation between text string that happen to be the same as built-in C++ operators, and the operators themselves. You will have to implement all of this yourself, manually. It will involve, perhaps, the use of a small associative container, and perhaps some lambdas. Both are medium-to-advanced C++ topics. Looks like your level of knowledge is still pretty basic, so I think you're better off focusing on continuing to read your C++ book, and practicing the specific examples, instead of trying to do something randomly, like this.

Comment: This looks like you're deep into [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory. What is the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Search the internet for "shunting yard algorithm c++".  You'll have to also consider precedence when evaluating operators.

Comment: @melpomene The original problem is this: how many combinations of 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9 = 100 where _ is either a +, -, or combine.